# How do I have a XSD complextype with *simple content* that has a restriction with enum values AND an extension

Tags: xml, enums, xsd

So how do I have a XSD complextype with *simple content* that has a restriction with enum values?

(!) Without an additional extra simple type:

*so ... kind of like this: -- only working ;)*
(please note that this a simplified example. see the xml I like to achieve)

```
        <element name="question">
            <complexType>
                <simpleContent>
                            <enumeration value="no"></enumeration>
                            <enumeration value="maybe"></enumeration>
                            <enumeration value="yes"></enumeration>
                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                    </extension>
                </simpleContent>
            </complexType>
        </element>
```

--

in the end this is a mock of the xml I have:

```
<question name="foo">
    yes
</question>
```

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_simpleContent.asp

Comment: Why do you want this to be a complex type, since there are no attributes and no child elements?

Comment: I thought the element name 'question' made it clear that this is only a minimal example. In the end I will definitely have a more complex type - **sorry**

Comment: I guess I'd have extension and restriction together and that can't be?

Comment: bonus: IF that is true, why would I ever have a complexType with only a restriction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following is what you had in mind. Create a simple type that restricts the values allowed, taking `xs:string` as the base. Then, extend this new, user-defined simple type in the `complexType` definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="question" type="questionType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="questionType" mixed="true">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="enumStringType">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string">
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="enumStringType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="no"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="maybe"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="yes"></xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note: This will only validate the following document:

```
<question name="foo">yes</question>
```

but not the one where the text content of `question` includes whitespace. To ignore any leading or trailing whitespace, or sequences of whitespace characters, you'd have to add the `whiteSpace` facet to the restriction:

```
<xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
```

Comment: thanks but: quote: "(!) Without an additional extra simple type:" -- with I knew too :) -- *but I take it it isn't possible then!?* Ill accept it

Comment: @Daij-Djan Sorry, I must have overlooked that. No, to my knowledge, it's not possible in a single `complexType` definition.